# getting multiple class selectors for select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get all select elements in a given div, even though they have different class names. It looks like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <select class="myclass">...</select>
    <select class="myotherclass">...</select>
</div>
```

I'd like to get all the selects with `myclass` or `myotherclass`. I've tried several ways but can't get it right.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
$.each($('[#mydiv select.myclass][#mydiv select.myotherclass]'), function(){ // handle stuff
$.each($('#mydiv select.myclass select.myotherclass'), function(){ // handle stuff
$.each($('#mydiv select.myclass myotherclass'), function(){ // handle stuff
```

and others, but I can't seem to get both selects into my element selection.

Comment: Have you tried $('#mydiv select').each()? You can get the class attribute as you loop...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

```
$('#mydiv select.myclass, #mydiv select.myotherclass')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($("#mydiv .myclass, #mydiv .myotherclass"), function(){ // handle stuff });
```

Comment: Separate calls to `$()` and `$.each` is inefficient

Comment: WTF! I was quoting the example given, the topic here is how to SELECT multiple classes

Comment: if this method is inefficient, is there a more effective way to accomplish the same thing? Thanks

Comment: Probably **$("#mydiv").find(".myclass, .myotherclass").each(function(){...})**. The difference is you first find **#mydiv** on the document and then perform 2 mini searches to it's children (instead of 2 at document level). That's a micro optimization only noticeable on large documents (browsers index the 'id' of the elements so it's fast anyway)

Comment: I'm not that sure of what @ExplosionPills says about calling **$()** and **$.each** is inefficient [citation needed](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wikipedian_protester.png) because **$.each** is handling just the iteration and of a given set of elements. [In the docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/#entry-longdesc) it reads "As always, remember that as a developer, your time is typically the most valuable resource. Do not focus on optimization of selector speed unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved."

Comment: @Xocoatzin it's faster to type `$().each` than it is to type `$.each($())`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I can't believe you down-voted me because **$.each($(),function(){})** is larger than **$().each(function(){})** by JUST 2 CHARs and typed on a different order. But you are right, you save some 100ms once in a lifetime by doing that.

Comment: @Xocoatzin it's also less performant and shows a lack of understanding of how the jQuery collection and `.each` work.  Also, your answer was a duplicate.

Comment: @ExplosionPills [Citation needed](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wikipedian_protester.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think it works with

```
$('#mydiv select.myclass, #mydiv select.myotherclass')
```

as in Css Selectors

Comment: Does not use `#mydiv` as requeseted

Answer (score 1):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$('#mydiv select').each(function(){
 console.log($(this));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsc78/)

Comment: @julio is that efficient with what you want..?

Comment: This also effective $('#mydiv select.myclass, #mydiv select.myotherclass') as for the selection different classes are separated by a comma.